# Click and Hold Event for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I go about having a click and hold event for Google Maps API? I am using `setTimeout` on a `click` event, but it does not work that great.

When I click and hold for 5 seconds on first try, it works great as the user is displayed with an alert message. But after the first try, it starts to show the alert message as you pan or zoom the map.

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Hello, World.");
        }, 5000);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t8hc0xte/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you 'hold' when you click the map is irrelevant... the event listener is activating as soon as you click.  It's just that you have your setTimeout set to 5 seconds that anything happens.

So when you click the map to drag it or adjust its zoom, that also triggers the 'click' event.

What you probably need is event listeners for the 'dragstart' and 'zoom_changed' events.  In these, set some sort of flag that prevents the alert happening, e.g. (this is untested, and I don't think will quite work, but gives you some idea):

```
var mapClicked = true;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
    mapClicked = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    mapClicked = true;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    mapClicked = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (mapClicked) {
            alert("Hello, World.");
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks duncan. It works, somewhat: http://jsfiddle.net/t8hc0xte/1/
I also tried using `mousedown` because I thought that would make more sense, but having some issues with it. Using `click` as you have described works though. The message displays 3 seconds after a click, but it's not necessarily the click and hold. Would be cool if Google includes in their events. I don't really want to use jQuery Mobile which has tap and hold event I think.